# How to create a configurable product made of simple products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I'd like to create a configurable product, a T-Shirt with different colors and size for example.
After following this tutorial http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-create-configurable-product/
It seems that the configurations are only virtual products and I didn't manage to get simple products, meaning no shipment possibility.

Do someone know a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify **Weight** in Current Variations grid to make product Simple. If leave this field empty product become virtual
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can config more custom options for product in Advanced Setting->Custom Options Tab.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a configurable product follow these steps-

1. Go to Products > Catalog
2. Click Add Product > Select Configurable product
   [image]
3. Fill the required details and click create configurations
   [image]
4. On configuration page, fill the relative information
   [image]
5. After Creating the configurations click Add Products Manually
   [image]
6. Select the products from the grid and click save button
   [image]
7. Product will be saved 
   [image]